# IOS : Cordova App Crash on Google Map api zoom in ios 11.3 iphone x

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, google-maps, cordova

I am developing one application with Cordova, AngularJs and OnsenUI,
I am using Google Maps Api to show my current location and around 200 other locations marker,

Google maps works fine in all other devices but app crashes when i zoom in IOS-11.3 with Iphone X only,

Cordova : 6.5.0
AngularJs 1
npm: 2.14.0

I have added firebase crash report plugin and it reported OOM(Out Of Memory) report for crash,

Marker image size is only 1kb and around 200 markers are there.
Here is my code

```
var mapProp = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(userlocation.latitude, userlocation.longitude),
                zoom: 12,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                MapOptions: {
                    zoomControl: false,
                    mapTypeControl: false,
                    scaleControl: false,
                    streetViewControl: false,
                    rotateControl: false,
                    fullscreenControl: false
                }

            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapNearByBreweries"), mapProp);
            var usermarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(userlocation.latitude, userlocation.longitude),
                icon: {
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    scale: 7,
                    strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                },
                draggable: false,
                map: map
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < breweries.length; i++) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(breweries[i].Latitude, breweries[i].Longitude),
                    map: map,
                    icon: 'images/blue-dot.png'
                //animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
            });
```

So, which new things in ios 11.3(IphoneX) can cause out of memory in google map api on zoom?

and what can i do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had this exact issue and rolling back to Google Maps version 3.31 worked for us :)

You can check out the different versions available here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases#321

Apparently they switched to an experimental renderer in 3.32 and it broke the fast zoom with custom markers for us.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Seeing the same issue here and 3.31 has been deleted. Are you seeing the same issue again or did you manage to fix some other way?

Comment: Having a similar issue with a web app on iOS 15.2.1 with Google Maps API (v. 3.47.7a) - what are you doing now to resolve this in the post 3.31 era?