# Cordova/Phonegap App Crash on GoogleMaps new API When Zoom with Marker on The Map

Tags: ios, reactjs, google-maps, cordova, phonegap

**UPDATE**: Problem solved with new released googlemaps api 3.35

**Problem**:

When trying to pinch (or double tap quickly) to zoom in, if there's marker on the mapview, the app may crash.

It didn't happen until Google releases their JS API 3.32 which uses a new map [renderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/new-renderer). We used to force using 3.31 but since [August](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases) it has been deleted.

**Using**:

- Phonegap: Phonegap cli-7.1.0, Cordova iOS 4.5.4
- iOS: 11, 12 (possibly all iOS versions)
- Devices: iPhone 8, iPhone X, iPad Pro (possibly all Apple devices)
- GoogleMaps JavaScript API: 3.32 - 3.34
- React: 16.2.0

**Google Maps Implementation** (tried in 4 ways):

- [react-google-maps](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps): crash
- [google-map-react](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react): crash
- [normal js implementation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers): **not crash**

  ```
  var marker1 = new window.google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: 39.304, lng: -76.617 },
      map: this.map
  });
  var marker2 = new window.google.maps.Marker({
      position: { lat: 39.305, lng: -76.616 },
      map: this.map
  });
  ```
- create a React component with normal js implementation: **crash**

  My Marker Component:

  ```
  class Marker extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
          const { position, icon } = this.props;
          this.marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
              position,
              icon
          });
      }

      componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
          const { map, position } = newProps;
          if (map && !this.marker.map) {
              this.marker.setMap(map);
          }
          if (position.lat !== this.props.position.lat || position.lng !== this.props.position.lng) {
              this.marker.setPosition(position);
          }
      }

      componentWillUnmount() {
          this.marker.setMap(null);
      }

      render() {
          return false;
      }
  }
  ```

  How I use this Component:

  ```
  {_.map(studyAreas, (s, i) => (
              <Marker
                  icon={s.icon}
                  position={s.position}
                  map={this.map}
                  key={i}
              />
          ))
  }
  ```

**Relevant Links**

[IOS : Cordova App Crash on Google Map api zoom in ios 11.3 iphone x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968769/ios-cordova-app-crash-on-google-map-api-zoom-in-ios-11-3-iphone-x)

https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/75

In the discussion of this github issue, it seems like they had this crashing problem because of some js libraries. However, I'm having this problem even when I created a simple new phonegap app without referencing any extra libraries.

Any help, discussion, thoughts would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I run into this issue, but where do you know **Problem solved with new released googlemaps api 3.35** ? Does Google announced ?

Comment: @OtsukiTakaya  I just tried the new api and it worked for me. Google didn't specify what's new in 3.35 though.